# Do any practical deep learning algorithms deal with tensors containing non-real entries?

Tags: deep-learning, datasets, applications, tensor

In deep learning, most of the applications are from text and images. Both text and images can be converted into a tensor of real numbers.

Other than both mentioned above, there may be some other real-world data used by Deep learning algorithms. Any algorithm in general takes tensor as input and gives tensor as output. As far as I know, tensors always consist of real numbers.

I want to know whether there are any practical applications that deal with the tensors containing non-real numbers. *Is there any such possibility*?

Comment: What about a Fourier transform of a time series?

Comment: @Dave I will check once.